# Export Datatable data to ajaxSource

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

i have a table, using datatables tag (http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/) that generates a typical dataTable.

```
<datatables:table id="myTableId" data="${persons}" row="person">
   <datatables:column title="Id" property="id" />
   <datatables:column title="FirstName" property="firstName" />
   <datatables:column title="LastName" property="lastName" />
   <datatables:column title="City" property="address.town.name" />
   <datatables:column title="Mail">
      <a href="mailto:${person.mail}">${person.mail}</a>
   </datatables:column>
</datatables:table>
```

I would like to get all the data generated as a Ajax souce, i guess something like

var sAjaxSource = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myTableId'));

to get store data in the variable with the typical Ajax format, something like this:

```
{
aaData: [
  hash1: [[1, "value1"], [2, "value2"]],
  hash2: [[3, "value3"], [4, "value4"]],
  hash3: [[5, "value5"], [6, "value6"]]
        ]
}
```

but this doesn't work. Is that possible ? Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done !

```
function array2dToJson(a, p, nl) {
              var i, j, s = '{"' + p + '":[';
              nl = nl || '';
              for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
                s += nl + array1dToJson(a[i]);
                if (i < a.length - 1) {
                  s += ',';
                }
              }
              s += nl + ']}';
              return s;
            }

var table = $('#myTableId').dataTable({'bRetrieve': true})
var data = table.fnGetData();
array2dToJson(data, 'data', '\n');
```